# How to decrease vertical space of shaded(\usepackage{framed}) environment?

Tags: framed

How to decrease the vertical space of `shaded` environment in preamble?
Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{color,xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\colorlet{shadecolor}{blue!11}

\begin{document}
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text texttext text text text text text text 
\begin{shaded}
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text texttext text text text text text text
\end{shaded}
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text texttext text text text text text text

text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text texttext text text text text text text
\end{document}
```

Please don't define the new environment, just change some properties of `shaded` environment.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Off topic: Do not load `color` but just the more modern `xcolor`.

You can redefine the vertical space by redefining the `framed`-internal length `OuterFrameSep`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\colorlet{shadecolor}{blue!11}
\setlength{\OuterFrameSep}{0pt}

\begin{document}
    text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text texttext text text text text text text 
    \begin{shaded}
        text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text texttext text text text text text text
    \end{shaded}
    text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text texttext text text text text text text

    text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text texttext text text text text text text
\end{document}
```

[image]